# Fluid Movement onClick from 1 position to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Please ignore the fact that only '(00 to 09)' is selected and the only one that works.

**My Goal with Jquery/Javascript**

I want whatever div that has the class .selected move up next to the random text. If you click on the button atm you will see that it snaps to the middle because of "text-align: center;". **EDIT**  I have achieved this part but now it to be a fluid movement not just a snap to appearance.

I want a nice fluid moving animation to nest the .selected div/button up next to the header 'Random Text' as in within the gray #topdiv  Then when clicking back on the .selected div button again.. it moves nicely back to it's former position and the other links are revealed again.

Currently I have the links fading and not fading and moving to the position I want. But you will see my issue when seeing the code live in the JSFiddle.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/csw6wy6j/5/

***HTML***

```
<div id="topdiv">
<h1>Random Text</h1>
</div>
<div id="adv2"> 
  <ul id="matrix-menu"> 
    <li><a href="#ani1" class="action-button shadow animate blue selected">00 to 09</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ani2" class="action-button shadow animate green">&nbsp;0 to 9&nbsp;</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#ani3" class="action-button shadow animate red">10 to 19</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#ani4" class="action-button shadow animate green">20 to 29</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#ani5" class="action-button shadow animate yellow">30 to 39</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ani6" class="action-button shadow animate blue">40 to 49</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#ani7" class="action-button shadow animate red">50 to 59</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#ani8" class="action-button shadow animate green">60 to 69</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#ani9" class="action-button shadow animate yellow">70 to 79</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#ani10" class="action-button shadow animate blue">80 to 89</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#ani11" class="action-button shadow animate red">90 to 99</a></li> 
  </ul> 
 </div>
```

***CSS***

```
#topdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ccc;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
#adv2 { float: left; 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  background: #333;
 }
.slideme {

}
#adv2 ul {
    margin: 0px 0 !important;    
    padding: 10px 0 0 0px !important;
    width: 99%;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px !important;
}

#adv2 #matrix-menu li { 
    /* float: left; */
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px !Important; 
}   

.animate
{
    transition: all 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
}

.action-button
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 40px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  float: left;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
.selected { background: #3C3C43 !important; }

.selected-pos {
    position: absolute;
    top: 37px;
    left: 230px;

}

.blue
{
    background-color: #3498DB;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2980B9;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #2980B9;
}

.red
{
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #BD3E31;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #BD3E31;
}

.green
{
    background-color: #82BF56;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #669644;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #669644;
}

.yellow
{
    background-color: #F2CF66;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #D1B358;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #D1B358;
}

.action-button:active
{
    transform: translate(0px,5px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,5px);
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

***JQUERY/Javascript***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#matrix-menu a").click(function(){
        $("#matrix-menu a").not(".selected").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear");
        $(".selected").not(".selected").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear");
        $(".selected").toggleClass("selected-pos");             
    });
});
```

Any advice or help with this would be GREATLY appreciated.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: You are using `inline-block` for the items. The position change is not controlled by any style property, so your `transition` is not working at all.

Comment: @JimmyKo thanks, I have updated it to do that. Now I just need the fluid look to it's position and back.